# Select the data in jTable but showing other data on jTextFields

Tags: java

when I select the table row normally, it's getting data correctly to JTextFields. But the question is when I searched a data then click on my Jtable its displays other data on Jtextfields. I want to get the correct data to JTextFields. Please help me!

I tried with these,

to search -->

```
getData(); 
        try{
            String sql = "Select * from member where mid = ?";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, txtSearch.getText());
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next())
            {
            String mid = rs.getString("mid");
            txtmid.setText(mid);
            String nic = rs.getString("NIC");
            txtnic.setText(nic);
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            txtname.setText(mid);
            String adress = rs.getString("adress");
            txtadress.setText(adress); 
        }  
      } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Operation Failed!");
        }
```

to click on JTable -->

```
// get the model from the JTable
        TableModel model =  tblmember.getModel();
        // get the selected row index
        int selectedRowIndex = tblmember.getSelectedRow();
        // set the selected row data into jtextfields
        txtmid.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString());
        txtnic.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString());
        txtname.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 2).toString());
        txtadress.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 3).toString());
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow :D Just as a hint, it's usually common to formulate all SQL-Query's in Caps, some SQL-driven systems even refuse to take anything else, I believe. However it's good practice to do so :)

Comment: Thank you for notify!